# How can I override the handler for a button in CKEditor?

Tags: save, overriding, ckeditor

I would like to have a custom handler for the <kbd>Save</kbd> button.

How can I override the default command?

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3350401/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Comment: cont' - Now deleted.

Answer (score 11):

The [current top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6408280/298212) messed up the toolbar grouping for me (put the save button at the end), and the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12879523/298212) did not work in CKEditor v4.

Here's how to do it in CKEditor 4:

HTML:

```html
<textarea id="CKEditor1"></textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```html
<script>
    // Need to wait for the CKEditor instance to finish initialization
    // because CKEDITOR.instances.editor.commands is an empty object
    // if you try to use it immediately after CKEDITOR.replace('editor');
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {

        // Create a new command with the desired exec function
        var editor = ev.editor;
        var overridecmd = new CKEDITOR.command(editor, {
            exec: function(editor){
                // Replace this with your desired save button code
                alert(editor.document.getBody().getHtml());
            }
        });

        // Replace the old save's exec function with the new one
        ev.editor.commands.save.exec = overridecmd.exec;
    });

    CKEDITOR.replace('CKEditor1');

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.registered['save']=
    {
     init : function( editor )
     {
        var command = editor.addCommand( 'save',
           {
              modes : { wysiwyg:1, source:1 },
              exec : function( editor ) {
                 //YOUR CODE
              }
           }
        );
        editor.ui.addButton( 'Save',{label : 'YOUR LABEL',command : 'save'});
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to override the *save* command for just one instance, you can try the following code:

```
var editor = $('#myTextarea').ckeditorGet(); // Retrieving CKeditor instance with jQuery
editor.getCommand('save').exec = function(editor) { 
    // Do whatever you need to
    ...
    return true;
};
```

This should work for any CKEditor command.

Comment: If you overwrite the exec function like this it will be called without any parameters. But since you normally have the `editor` variable in the outer scope you could still work with it. Just remember to leave out the `editor` parameter in your function definition because it would otherwise overwrite your scoped `editor` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
function configureEditor(id) {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace(id);
    editor.on("instanceReady", function () {
        // Overwrite the default save function
        editor.addCommand("save", {
            modes: { wysiwyg: 1, source: 1 },
            exec: function () {
                // get the editor content
                var theData = editor.getData();
                alert("insert your code here");
            }
        });
        editor.ui.addButton('Save', { label: 'My Save', command: 'save', enabled: 'true' });
        var saveButton = $('#cke_' + id).find('.cke_button__save');
        saveButton.removeClass('cke_button_disabled');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CKEditor 4, the save plugin is meant to be cancelable. If unsure, one can always have a look at the [source](http://docs.ckeditor.com/source/plugin78.html#CKEDITOR-editor-event-save%22%20title=%22example%22). You can cancel the event and apply your own logic in a handler, like in this example:

```javascript
// Assuming 'editor' is a CKEDITOR.editor instance
editor.on('save', function (event) {
    event.cancel();
    // Your custom command logic
    // (You can access the editor instance through event.editor)
});
```

I would advise against creating a new command and replacing the default with it, as it is an unnecessary workaround.